# HTML onclick behaviour not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon

I have the following HTML code:

```
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>BibTeX Maker</title>
    <script src="sidebar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
      <button onclick="getData()">Click me</button>
      <span id="myText"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var HttpClient = function() { //some code };

function getData(){
    var response = client.get('https://reference-extraction.herokuapp.com/api/references/download?url=' + url + '&document_type=full_paper&reference_style=ensemble&reference_format=bibtex&engine=v1', function(response) {
        document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = response
    });
};
```

I am passing the value of `response` to HTML id `"myText"`. 
However, it is not showing me any output. Why is that?

edit: I have added the full code.

Comment: getData? getInfo? wrongly put the function name?

Comment: Sorry, changed everything to getData in the question. Still no output. This is for firefox addon.

Comment: Please check the URL, which u r calling. client.get('https://websiteName+url)

Comment: The URL is long so I just said, https://websiteName but it is:     var response = client.get('https://reference-extraction.herokuapp.com/api/references/download?url=' + url + '&document_type=full_paper&reference_style=ensemble&reference_format=bibtex&engine=v1', function(response) {

Comment: few steps to check this, first u need to make sure getDate() function been fired, and then u need to check https://websiteName have response, like check the network console in debug mode.

Comment: Yes, if I go the developer mode in FireFox, the getData() works and I get a response. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/Uv7At2o.png)

Comment: As you can see, on the right, we get response from the URL. But why can't I get the response as HTML output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var response = client.get('https://reference-extraction.herokuapp.com/api/references/download?url=' + url + '&document_type=full_paper&reference_style=ensemble&reference_format=bibtex&engine=v1', function(response) {
        document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = response
    });
```

There are two response in your code which might be the confusion. rename one response to some other name. since "function(response)" is the response returning from the server.

Or either directly call like this:

```
client.get('https://reference-extraction.herokuapp.com/api/references/download?url=' + url + '&document_type=full_paper&reference_style=ensemble&reference_format=bibtex&engine=v1', function(response) {
            document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = response
        });
```

finally, is there any response returning from the server?

Comment: hooray... glad it did :)

Answer (score 0):

On the HTML you are calling getinfo()   `<button onclick="getinfo()">Click me</button>`

while its suppose to be getData(). So I think the correct way would be   `<button onclick="getData()">Click me</button>`

Comment: Sorry, changed everything to getData in the question. Still no output. This is for firefox addon.

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).

Comment: The Content Security Policy (CSP) prevents XSS attacks. you can read more here https://content-security-policy.com/

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you. 
var HttpClient = function() { //Some code }; 
this line was causing problem

```
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>BibTeX Maker</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getData(){
                if (window.location.href.indexOf("pdf") != -1) {
                    var url = window.location.href;
                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    var response = client.get('https://websiteName + url', function(response) {
                    document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = response});
                } else {
                    alert("Error: Not a PDF File");
                }
            }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
      <button onclick="getData()">Click me</button>
      <span id="myText"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hold on, I will paste the full code in the question above and you can see.

Comment: @SamanRay Please paste the above-mentioned code which I have answered into a new file and test, It will work :)